# Shared element transition not working properly

Tags: android

[please watch this video to know the exact issue](https://streamable.com/seljd)

As my transition element is not properly getting animated when it's not completely visible but it works very well when it's visible.

Comment: Your issue is about transition overlapping the top bar?

Comment: Yes...that's right

Answer (score -1):

Disable the overlay by using this in your XML:

`android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay="false"`

**OR**

Exclude the status bar from the window's default enter/exit transition by:

```
Transition fade = new Fade();
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
```

Comment: Hey thnx for the input..but can you tell me exactly which xml, source or destination?...I have recyclerview's item as source xml...

Comment: Use it for the destination XML. If it doesn't work, I've added a second method.

Comment: okay ill try this, but that blue part is a tab layout will it work with same solution?? or any extra effort is needed?

Comment: Try passing in your tab layout id for `excludeTarget()`